# cakephp 2.x form validation with model but without database

Tags: cakephp

i am very new to cakephp i trying to validate  contact forms.i need a validation without database tables in models.but it is not working.code which i used shown below

folllowing is the code :ContactsController.php

```
<?php
class ContactsController extends AppController {


  var $uses='Contact';

  public function index() {
        // Placeholder for index. No actual action here, everything is submitted to the send function.
    }

    public function send() {
            $this->Contact->set($this->data);
            if($this->Contact->validates()) {
       echo "hiiii";
}
        }




}
----------------------------Model-----------------------
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class ContactModel extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Contact';
    var $useTable = false;

    var $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'message' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true
        )
    );
}
-----------------------in view/Contacts/index.ctp-----------------------------
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Contact', array('action' => 'Contacts/send'));
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('message',array('rows' => 3));
echo $this->Form->submit('Submit');
?>
```

Comment: Try with else condition where you used validates() in `if condition`. And in else condition write `pr($this->Contact->invalidFields());`, tell what happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689232/cakephp-validate-error

Comment: reult of this  in else condition write pr($this->Contact->invalidFields()); isArray ( [name] => Array ( [0] => This field cannot be left blank [1] => This field cannot be left blank ) [email] => Array ( [0] => This field cannot be left blank [1] => This field cannot be left blank ) [message] => Array ( [0] => This field cannot be left blank [1] => This field cannot be left blank ) )

Comment: I think you get the all result to display. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to validate without using models, which can also be used for forms, at least in CakePHP2.

For example, I had to validate params and I saw no point in creating models for each action that requires params.

So, I used this:

1. Before the controller class declaration

   App::uses('Validation', 'Utility');
2. In the action with a $code param

   function checkcode($code) {
       ...
       Validation::alphaNumeric($code);
       ...
   }

Answer (score 0):

this article will give you all the information needed:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/15/tools-plugin-part-2-contact-form/

especially how to use _schema to build your validation and forms the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

$this->Contact->save() should call the Validation from associated model.

```
public function send() {
        $this->Contact->set($this->data);
        if($this->Contact->save()) {
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('Contact saved!'));
        }
}
```