# CakePhp: read View rule message inside controller

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I've declared my validation fields of my view in this way:

```
public $validate = array(
    'myField' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'username required'
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'required' => 'create',
            'message' => 'Username already used'
        )
    )
);
```

Is there a way to know (inside the relative controller class) when this message is fired?
Because if one of these rules is violated, I would like to perform some tasks, and not simply show message to the user.

Comment: see & try  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4693494/2460470.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first set the data to the model in your controller:

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->request->data);
```

Then, to check if the data validates, use the validates method of the model, which will return true if it validates and false if it doesn’t:

```
if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    // it validated logic
} else {
   // didn't validate logic
   $errors = $this->ModelName->validationErrors;
}
```

To know more about `validationErrors`, go to cakephp [Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html) article.